# Unify Authentication

Tags: java, angularjs, authentication

I have a challenge in my job. We have two applications with different functionalities, which I need to unify authentication. 
The solution we thought was to create a page that will redirect to the chosen application. The thing is, i have no idea how to unify these authentications. 
Can someone help me?

The applications are using angularJs and java

Comment: Hey there! Please, try to read your question with a mindset and knowledge of someone who does not work in your company and try to rephrase and expand on your question. Asking questions correctly is an art you have to master before you start getting useful results.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is to separate the identity function as a separate service and let both the services use the identify service to authenticate and authorize.